# Twilio Room Creation take too long time to return a response

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video, twilio-python

I am working on a creating video platform and in that, I used Twilio service. It is working fine for me but Video Room creation takes around 10-15 seconds. How to optimize video room creation?

I followed the same code format as they provided on their docs. I implemented this code in Python.

```py
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

room = client.video.rooms.create(unique_name='DailyStandup')
```

Comment: It should not take that long to create a room with the API. Is there anything else you are doing at the same time?

Comment: For me, creating a twilio room takes about less than 500ms, so you probably are doing something else or the issue is related to another thing. Also, check if you are using the default region (you can explicitly define a preferred region).